# Is it okay to have the same preposition/pronoun consecutively?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns

If I write a phrasal verb or an idiom (what do you call it?), is it okay to have the same preposition after?

> I don't fit in in this world.

"Fit in" is a phrasal verb, right? Is it okay to have another "in" after it?

And, for the pronoun case.

> There's no limit if you think about it it exists.

A lyric I wrote, is it okay to have "it it"? Or should I put a comma between them? Which I doubt.

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation, "I don't fit in in this world" would be understood, and many native speakers might say the exact same sentence. However, if this were a written sentence, it would be a good idea to revise the sentence to remove the awkward repetition. Here are some possible revisions:

> I don't fit in with this world.
>
> I don't fit into this world.
>
> In this world, I don't fit in.

This kind of repetition can occur with other phrasal verbs. Here are some examples:

> The conflict will blow over over the weekend.
>
> Here are some clothes you can try on on the runway.
>
> Could you pitch in in the kitchen?

Again, these are all "ok" grammatically, but they are poor choices *stylistically*.

---

Your pronoun example does not quite make sense. It seems to be a run-on sentence. I'm not sure if these alternatives have exactly the meaning you intend, but you could try:

> There's no limit. If you think about it, it exists.
>
> There's no limit if you think about it. It exists.

However, some sentences *could* have repeated pronouns in this way:

> The robot's wheels were covered in dirt. Behind it it left dark tracks on the carpet.

Again, this might be a correct sentence, but it would be much better to rephrase the sentence to remove the awkward "it it", even with a simple comma between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I think It is not okay, you should probably use only one proposition in this case, to me I have never come across this case, there are a two propositions phrasal verbs like: to cut ***down on*** fatty foods in your case I think the first *in* is sufficient why you have added the second *in*  I think it is better to you saying instead :I don't fit in ***with*** this world ! see more examples on the link her below.
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fit-in?fallbackFrom=british-grammar